# Preventing memory leaks in react-konva

Tags: memory-leaks, konvajs, react-konva

The Konva library has a [helpful list of performance optimizations](https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html). I am writing an application using react-konva and would like to specifically know if there is any work to be done when a component is unmounted to prevent memory leaks. Do I need to destroy() any konva elements for cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about mem-leaks with `react-konva`. It automatically handles adding/destroying shapes.

You only need to apply the rules from the link if you:

1. Create nodes manually in some react lifecycle methods (you probably should not do that).
2. Use `Konva.Tween` functions manually. But in that case, just need to destroy it, as in the docs.

If you are just rendering shapes in "react-way" with `render()` function, you will be fine.